# How to use all oprator in sql server

Tags: sql

My query:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM   tbl_emp
WHERE  salary > ALL (4000, 3000, 3500)
```

Gives an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '4000'.

Comment: Do you want "salary > 4000 and salary > 3000 and salary > 3500"?

Comment: user72380 do not forget as correct answer If It helped for you.

Comment: I take this query from internet and trying to run on my pc i also create the database but showing error

Comment: Yeah, it was on the Internet, at it doesn't work... Internet is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

**[ALL](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_all.php)** is used to select all records of a SELECT STATEMENT.

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM tbl_emp 
WHERE salary > ALL(  
                   SELECT salary 
                   FROM tbl_2
                   WHERE anything = something
                   )
```

Your question seems not logical, you can just specify

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM tbl_emp 
WHERE salary > 4000
```

Why you need to tell `WHERE salary > 3000, 3500, 3700`, etc.. It always will be true if `WHERE salary > 4000`

Comment: ok 
SELECT name, salary
FROM tbl_emp 
WHERE salary > ALL(  
                   SELECT salary 
                   FROM tbl_dept
                   WHERE salary > 4000
                   )  
Thanks!

Comment: @user72380 Accept It as correct answer (select `V` in top left of answer).